# Как в форме регистрации/авторизации добавить подключение к БД и добавление пользователя в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, auth

- Sign in
- Sign up

```
<div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
    <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
        <ul class="cd-switcher">
            <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">New account</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
        <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                    <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldset" style="text-align: center;">
                    Or
                </p>
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <a class="waves-effect btn grey darken-3 col s12" href="https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com%2Fajax%2FlogInWithSteam&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select"><input class="full-width"  value="Steam"></a>
                </p>
            </form>


            <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
            <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
        </div> <!-- cd-login -->

        <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
            <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                    <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                    <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a href="#0">Terms</a></label>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">
                </p>
            </form>

            <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
        </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

        <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
            <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>

            <form class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
                </p>
            </form>

            <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a></p>
        </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключение к базе:

```
<?
$sql_link = mysqli_connect(АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА,ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ_БД,ЕГО_ПАРОЛЬ,БАЗА_ПО_УМАЛЧАНИЮ,ПОРТ_СЕРВЕРА);
//Первые 3 параметра, как правило в большинстве случаев понадобятся, остальные опциональны по надобности.
?>
```

Более детально можно почитать тут:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php